# alfresco alvex uploader: how can upload just pdf files?

Tags: alfresco

i want to use in alfresco the alvex uploader just to grab the pdf files on my computer or repo,
i have tried to:

`<field id="env:attachment" label-id="attach.doc.label" set="table>`
`<control template="/alvex-uploader.ftl">`
  `<control-param name="uploadDirectory">uploads</control-param>`
 `<control-param name="createUploadDirectory">true</control-param>`
 `<control-param name="allowedExtensions">pdf</control-param>`
  `</control>`
`</field>`

but is not working.

Comment: Please post the errors if anything you getting. Will you be able to upload other than PDF files?

Comment: I got none errors, even i change the argument inside the allowedExtensions to .pdf *.pdf

Comment: You no need to mention any file extensions, in default it will allow all the files.

Comment: But i want just pdf files.